# Set the margins of an imageView by programming inside a constraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to program the margin of the ImageView inside the ConstraniLayout2 with this code

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
            imageView.getLayoutParams();
            newLayoutParams.topMargin = 140;
            newLayoutParams.leftMargin = 400;
            newLayoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
            newLayoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;

            imageView.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
```

With this code I program the site of the imageView but of the entire screen of the smartphone.
How can I program the imageView to switch places with the constrainLayout2 references?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to set the margin using ConstraintSet.
Below is a snippet you can try

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayoutId)
val marginTop = context.getDimension(10f)
constraintSet.setMargin(R.id. imageView, ConstraintSet.TOP, marginTop)
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayoutId)

fun Context.getDimension(value: Float): Int {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value, this.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm new to programming and I don't know how to use klotin, I only use java.